# XSLT -- detect if node has already been copied to the result tree

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Using xsltproc to clean up input XML.

Think about a part number referencing a part description from random locations in the document. My XML input is poorly designed and it has part number references to part descriptions all over with no real pattern as to where they are located. Some references are text in elements, some in attributes, sometimes the attribute changes meaning depending on context. The attribute containing the part number does not have a consistent name, the name used alters depending on the value of other attributes. Maybe I could build a key selecting the dozen varying places containing part number but it would be a mess. I would also worry about inadvertently selecting the wrong items with complex patterns.

So my goal is to only copy the referenced part descriptions to the output document once (not all descriptions are referenced). I can insert tests in all of the various templates to detect the part number in context. The very simple solution would be to just test if it has already been copied to the result tree and not copy it again.  But there is no way to track this?

Plan B is to copy it multiple times to the result tree and then do a second pass over the output document to remove the duplicates.

Comment: It sounds to me as if Plan B is the easiest, safest, and most robust, but may not be the most performant.

Comment: A  result tree in XSLT 1 is not some data structure where you can identify nodes. It would seem to be easier to identify the first reference in the input tree although your description sounds as if that is challenging. And it is also not clear what kind of result structure you are trying to build, if it is a plain list of part description then even in XSLT 1 using a parameter passing on the already processed input description nodes plus the union of the currently processed one might suffice to eliminate duplicates and output the list in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The use of temporal language in the question (*"has already been"*) is a good clue that you're thinking about this the wrong way. In a declarative language, you shouldn't be thinking in terms of the order of processing.

What you're probably looking for is something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="first-of-a-kind-part-references" as="node()*">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="f:all-part-references(/)" 
                       group-by="f:get-referenced-part(.)/@id">
     <xsl:sequence select="current-group()[1]"/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then when processing a part reference

```
<xsl:if test=". intersect $first-of-a-kind-part-references">
  ...
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: *"In a declarative language, you shouldn't be thinking in terms of the order of processing."*
 
I agree with the concept in general, but... The fact is that templates are executed in the order they apply/call other templates - so the question "did I already do this" is at least meaningful, if not legitimate. And if this were entirely true, one would never get an error message saying *"An attribute node cannot be created after a child of the containing element."*

Comment: The error message cited is a shorthand for "An attribute node cannot appear in the result sequence of a sequence constructor after an element, text, comment, or processing-instruction node". When designing error messages, there's a trade-off between making the message easy to understand and making it strictly accurate.

Comment: I am afraid you are missing my point. It's not about the language of the error message. It's about the limitation that the error message represents. A limitation that would not exist if the order of processing weren't significant.

Comment: It's true that the spec defines this error condition in order to allow processors to execute the instructions sequentially in the order they are written. But it's not true that the spec guarantees that the processor will execute them in this way.

Comment: But the net effect of this limitation is that it forces the stylesheet author to be "thinking in terms of the order of processing". In a purely declarative language the order of the instructions would not matter.

Comment: The ordering of the nodes in the output is dependent on the ordering of instructions in the stylesheet. That's not at all the same as saying that the instructions are executed in the order they are written.

Comment: You keep missing my point. I don't care one bit how the processor executes the instructions under the hood. OP asked how to detect if node has already been copied to the result tree. You told them not to be thinking in terms of order of processing. If I am not thinking in terms in order of processing, then I should not be asking myself "did I already add children to this element" before adding an attribute.